# Encourage tag wiki creation/edits by awarding more reputation to editors

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits, tag-wiki

Right now, editing a tag wiki earns you +2 rep points.

Considering that most tag wikis have no content whatsoever, shouldn't we encourage people to write tag wikis and fill in these gaps for additional reputation?

I think tag wikis are very important: they help people ask better questions and provide better answers, both of which are good for the site.

I also suggest that this bonus gets awarded by a moderator, to prevent people from taking advantage of this to get rep they don't deserve.

As per [Will's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will-dont-give-a) [suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91739/encourage-tag-wiki-creation-edits-by-awarding-more-reputation-to-editors/91787#91787), the cap on users' cap should be removed, since we want people with good experience on the topic to participate in wikis as well.

Comment: It doesn't earn you zip for points if you have over 2k rep. You're lucky to get +2!

Comment: @Cody No wonder no one bothers, then.

Comment: @Cody Actually, you get +2 as long as you haven't earned 1000 yet from suggested edits. ChrisF used tag wikis to help usher him from 2000 to 3000 on Gaming. Once you hit *20000*, *then* you won't earn reputation for such suggestions.

Comment: @Grace: Oh, I see what you're saying. I was thinking about people who didn't have to use the suggested edits feature to edit them. Like tags where you're in the top 20 answers.

Comment: @Cody I was under the impression that that system was removed (on account of being terribly unintuitive and hard to figre) in favor of just having suggested edits for all users with less than 2000 reputation.

Comment: @Grace: Hmm, it looks like they have. I had no idea. I suppose that's good to know. :-)

Answer (score 8):

My take on this is quite simple, instead of trying to figure out better ways of voting on edits we could simply allow for bounties on tag wikis. The way I envisage this working:

1. User can add a bounty on any tag wiki (minimum of 100 points)
2. At the end of the bounty he may award it to any of the editors (provided they made a minimal amount of change)
3. Consider auto-awarding to the person who edited most in the time window

By keeping this in the bounty system it would help cut down on some gaming issues and heavily promote tag wikis we care about. If we had bounties I would place a 100 point bounty on the dapper tag wiki :)

Comment: Dapper?  [Dapper Dan](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ3P6.jpg)?

Comment: almost ... http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dapper/topusers

Comment: Edited most? won't that encourage copy-pasting?

Comment: @MahmoudHossam details are not final, I don't know how this will work, just toying with the idea

Answer (score 2):

There would have to be some kind of metric to ensure that people don't try to game that system.  The wiki would have to be in the default state, and the edit be of a minimum length and not be edited for a period of time.  I do think that there should be some greater incentive to users to work on improving tag wikis, so +1 from me.

Comment: Maybe give them +2 for editing, and more if it gets approved by a moderator?

Comment: @MahmoudHossam: I also don't think there should be a cap on user rep.  You should *want* your high-rep users contributing to tag wikis.

Comment: @Will I think that could be done as well, but that should be in another thread.

Comment: @MahmoudHossam: Fits in with the question title, does it not?

Comment: @Will If the question won't be closed as "Too broad", then I don't mind adding that at all, feel free to edit the question :)

Comment: @MahmoudHossam: Its a discussion about encouraging wiki edits by adjusting reputation awards to editors.  I seriously think my comment is well within the scope.

Comment: @Will okay, done.

Answer (score 2):

The creation of tag wikis, in a certain degree, *does* provide more reputation. It provides +4, because every tag wiki consists of two separate posts - the excerpt and the body. As such, you get +2 for each, for a total of +4.

When creating a new wiki, it's a very simple task to provide both (I don't recall if it's required, as it's simply *good practice* to do both anyway). Editing an existing one, it's not so much necessary, but it will still be worth +4 if you had enough reason to edit both of them.

As these are just suggested edits, they follow all of the standard rules, which helps prevent them from being fully gamed. There's a maximum of +1000 reputation you can earn in this method, and they are affected by the daily reputation cap as well. 1000 sure sounds like a lot, but if you think about it, that's a whole *250* wikis you need to write. I think it's pretty fairly balanced as a result.