# Optional bonus rep for excellent tag wiki suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Tag wiki's are **unique** from post edits in that they often are a lot more than a copy edit. Often, editors will pour a good chunk of time into a **great tag wiki edit** that adds paragraphs of excellent material and get two rep as a reward. However, if they wrote that same edit as an answer to a question, they could have gotten boatloads more rep.

**I propose a tag wiki suggested edit bonus that can be awarded by reviewers from their own rep for an outstanding tag wiki edit**.

The amount doesn't really matter as much as the recognition that, *"hey, this is a **great** edit and is an **exceptional example** of a tag wiki edit."*

Perhaps another qualification should be added to prevent abuse, such as X reviewers have to agree that the edit is deserving of it. Another idea is to award a badge (like [Good-Answer]) instead of rep that can be accumulated for X great tag wiki edits.

---

*The manner of recognizing those outstanding edits is not as important as recognizing these edits and the individuals behind the scene who have put forth their time and effort to make Stack Exchange a better place.*

Comment: So this would just be for suggested editors, not for editors that already have tag wiki editing privileges?

Comment: As the system is now, only suggested edits are reviewed, so it would be harder to review edits by users with tag wiki editing privileges unless another queue for tag wiki edits was added for the sole purpose of awarding this recognition.

Comment: Related: [Encourage tag wiki creation/edits by awarding more reputation to editors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91739/encourage-tag-wiki-creation-edits-by-awarding-more-reputation-to-editors)

Answer (score 6):

Tag wikis get a *lot* of bad suggested edits as it is, and worse still, many reviewers are very bad at reviewing tag wikis.  They just aren't very familiar with the guidelines, or what makes a good/bad tag wiki.  As a result we even see a lot of bad tag wiki edits get approved.

If tag wiki edits always, or even optionally, get additional reputation you're going to see a *lot* more of them, and most of them won't be that good; it will just be people spamming out lots of them in the hopes of getting in on that rep action.  Given the state of the current review system, many of them are likely to even get approved, and even get approved with the extra rep, which only encourages this type of behavior.

If the review queue was in such a state that we could reliably trust that only good edits were approved, and only great edits were given such a bonus, then this is something that could be *considered*.  Until then, there's no way this could be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps only reviewers with X reviews or X rep can award the bonus. This would stop bad edits from being awarded the bounty.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid this would be the most probable outcome.  It's an interesting suggestion, but I would be more in favor of something that motivates those that already have tag wiki editing privileges.

Comment: Perhaps if the tag wiki edit adds over X characters, it is automatically added to an (existing?) queue for the option of the bonus.

Comment: @AmericanLuke I highly doubt it.  The worst reviewers are the ones going around approving stuff really fast, without reading the content, or at least not reading it closely, not taking their time, etc.  They often have *lots* of reviews, because they're only there to do as many reviews in as little time as possible.

Comment: I guess, I just don't see that as much on smaller sites where I usually hang out.

Comment: @AmericanLuke A char limit is also a poor indicator.  One of the major problems is people just plagiarizing content from Wikipedia or other sources, just copy-pasting such text into tag wikis.  This can rather often be lots of characters, it's just that those characters aren't useful.