# Next-generation tag wikis that leverage simple conventions to empower your creativity

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

A lot of tag wikis contain vague buzzwords and read like advertisements.

Take, for example, the excerpt of the tag wiki of the aurelia tag on Stack Overflow:

> A next generation JavaScript client framework that leverages simple conventions to empower your creativity.

This tells me precisely nothing. It seems like it is the tagline copied from the website of the technology in question.

Are such tag wikis considered good? Should they be removed or edited?

Comment: Perhaps there could be a sort of tag description voting system, weighted against reputation and/or answer quality?

Comment: It should be edited.

Comment: @Cinch: Only if bad tags are a huge global problem. It depends on what amount is "a lot" in this case.

Comment: @wilx mmm, yes, but we must also consider that some people don't have the interest to edit normally. Perhaps some sort of incentive would help this problem.

Comment: @Cinch: I think this is what we have review queue for. The reviewers just need to be instructed to watch out for this particular problem as well.

Comment: +1 A nice and phuunny question, while being serious overall.

Comment: @Cinch - If for a user "helping out the site and it's users, and making it a better place" is not incentive enough, then that user shouldn't be editing tag wikis. See servy's answer here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203868/230506

Answer (score 6):

> Are such tag wikis considered good?

The specific one you listed as an example is not really good, no.

> Should they be removed or edited?

If you mean remove the *tag*, then you need to raise a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) question on the relevant site, suggesting which tag is not useful, too generic, dupe or could be a synonym etc.

If you mean remove the *description* then they should be edited if they are no good or could be improved.  If that means re-writing the entire thing as the current text is completely gobbledegook, then sure wipe it clean and start again.

Essentially, the target is "improvement", and that leaving all, some, or none of the current text depends on the specific tag and current text.

> A lot of tag wikis contain vague buzzwords and read like
>   advertisements.

I agree, however this is what community moderating is there for, so we can as a community improve things and suggest edits to tag wikis and such like.
Then if the general consensus is an edit suggestion improves the tag wiki/excerpt, then it will be approved.

I'm not sure (exactly) what problem you are reporting, other than there are *some* poor tag wikis/excerpts which could be improved.
Yes there are some terrible tag wikis and excerpts, so just edit them :)

---

There are also thousands of *good* tag wiki and excerpts, so I don't think there is a large enough issue here to be concerned or to have to do anything specific or new.
Just edit them as and when you see poor ones, or when any improvement can be made.

Comment: Note that I have not had good success with suggesting edits that blow away even the most useless wikis. I suggest including a ridiculously descriptive edit summary if you do try this, linking to this meta question at the very least.